# Event with multiple days - multiple choices

Tags: custom-templates

I can't seem to find exactly what I need. So here it goes. We are having our annual meeting, but this year there are essentially 3 events that people can choose to go to and I will need name tags for each of the events.

- Event 1 Tour is at a distillery and can only have 20 people cost is $10.
- Event 2 Dinner is at a Farm and can only have 40 people cost is $30.
- Event 3 is the next day and can have 125 to 150 people and costs $35.

I would like the person registering for the annual meeting to be able to sign:

- person A up for all the events
- person B up for just the annual meeting
- person C only for the distillery tour.

I've tried setting up event costs but it doesn't give me the place to add people's name for a name tag.

How can I set up Attendee 1 First Name - Last Name Event 1 Event 2 Event 3 - total cost.
Attendee 2 First Name - Last Name Event 2 total cost

FINAL COST - $x.xx to paypal..
Right now it is multiple logins with multiple payments to  paypal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called [price sets](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/complex-event-fees/) - in combination with the "multiple register participants" feature.

- Set up the price set with **Events menu » New Price Set**.  See screenshot 1 below.
- Once you save the price set, you'll new to create a *price field*.  Configure it similarly to screenshot 2 below.
- If the annual meeting also has a cost, or there are other optional items, add those as additional price fields.
- When configuring the event, on the **Fees** tab, change **Price Set** to the price set you just configured.  Note that this will replace your existing pricing, so make sure it's added to the price set.
- On the event's **Online Registration** tab, check the **Register multiple participants?** checkbox.

That's it!  When someone registers for an event, they'll select how many people (see screenshot 3) and fill in the info for themselves (including payment info).  Then when they continue, they'll get a page for each of the next registrants where they can select individually (screenshot 4).  Screenshot 5 is my confirmation page, where you can see I've signed up three people with different options and collected all their names.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am going to attempt to set this up. Again I'm new to all of this so ..  BUT THANK YOU THANK YOU for the help.

Comment: @Deb If you run into trouble, come ask for help on https://chat.civicrm.org!

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE YOU GUYS ROCK. i wish I could take a class on this. 
Too much to learn and not enough hours in the day.

Comment: @Deb where are you based?  There are one-day and two-day classes all the time.  There's one this month in Oakland, and I believe another in NYC in June, along with non-US ones in the meantime.